Movies about a man who meets a girl on a biking trip and ends up being haunted through the forest by hillbillies
This movie is from the early/mid 2000s. The movie revolves around a man who goes on a solo biking trip in the woods around autumn time. He ends up stopping at a cottage/tavern type of place, where he notices 2 hill billies hitting on a girl who is also on a solo biking trip. He stops them from hitting on the girl, and they start talking to each other. They end up getting together and continuing their trip in the forest when the hillbillies start hunting them with guns. 
They get to a certain part of the forrest where some sort of monster manages to kidnap them all, and put them in his weird psychiatric hospital, where he ends up torturing them by placing them on a bed made of pure iron, and heating the iron up so that their skin melts and becomes attached to the bed. 
The end of the movie has a massive twist, where he actually ends up being a soldier who gets his leg blown off by a mine, and the girl is actually the nurse that was taking care of him, and the hillbillies were his soldier friends, and the camera pans out to see him laying in a hospital bed with no legs.

I believe you are looking for Shadow from 2009. The blurb on IMDB says 

When a young soldier leaves for a mountain biking excursion, he meets the girl of his dreams as well as a group of violent locals who want to see them dead at any cost.

And one of the reviews mentions the same twist at the end that you described.
Here is the trailer 


